# Can't get activity-result via hierarchical structured activities when going up and down the tree

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, start-activity

I've got the following problem:
There are the Activities A, B, C and D.
Each Activity of B, C and D contain a list of items.

Now let's start at A:
From A i want to go to Activity D to select an Item and put it in somewhere in A.
But to get from A to D I've got to go through B and C.
That is because B, C and D represent a tree of objects.

So I start the activities the following way:
A => B => C => D
in the end I want to pass the item from D to A.

Up to that my code is working correctly!

But:
Imagine the user chose the wrong item in Activity C. Therefore he will get the false list in Activity D.
What would the user do? The user would go back to C, choose the correct item, so the correct list in D will be shown.
Then the user will choose the wanted item in D, which shall be passed back to Activity A.

That doesn't work.
So whenever the user uses the back-button to get one level back in the tree, the code doesn't work anymore.

Specifically it doesn't work because if I went back from D to C the Activity C does not have a calling Activity anymore (actvityC.getCallingActivity() is null).

To go from A to B I use startActivityForResult().
To go from B to C and from C to D I use startActivity() and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT.

I hope you understand my problem and can help me.

Greetings

edited: typo removed

Answer (score 0):

An interesting problem!

To solve this, you need to override `onBackPressed()` in `ActivityD` like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
    // add any necessary extras here
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and you probably need to override `onBackPressed()` in `ActivityC` also, so that is does the same thing going back to `ActivityB`.

---

However...another alternative, which might be easier to implement, is not to use `startActivityForResult()` at all. A can just start B. B can start C and C can start D and when the user actually chooses something in D, then D can return the result directly to A like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
// add whatever extras you want to send back to A
startActivity(intent);
```

This will remove activities D, C and B from the stack and call `onNewIntent()` on the existing instance of `ActivityA`.

If you need to pass extras from A to B to C to D, you can just add them to the `Intent` that gets used to start B, C and D respectively.

In `ActivityA` you will need to override `onNewIntent()` where you can capture the `Intent` sent back by `ActivityD`.

Comment: First, thank you! I solved it by using startActivityForResult() in each Activity of A, B and C. When an item in D is selected, then I give it back by setting the result and firing finish() in D, C and B (in this order). I think this solution is a bit hacky because I resume C and B and close them directly afterwards. So I'll implement one of your solutions in a few days (no time by now). If it works, I'll upvote your answer, of course :)